# online 3D modelling software (like sketchup)

Tags: software-rec, cloud, 3d-modeling, cad, sketchup

I'm at school and I need to use a 3D modelling software for my Tech project, however there current one is quite old and has a steep learning curve. As I'm at school I can't download or install or execute any software like Sketchup, and the my teacher has asked for it be installed on the computers, however it hasn't happened since I asked a week ago. So the only alternative is for me to find an online tool, in the same way Google Docs is online, this gets me round the policy of not running an software on school computers.

Sadly the only browser on the computers is IE8, so it would probably have to be flash based, rather than HTML5 or anything that requires a plugin (other than Flash).

In sum, I'm looking for a cloud-based/online 3D modelling tool.

Comment: Err no that question is asking about drawing a simple polygon online my question is about a program as complicated as sketchup.

Comment: Actually, this question like the duplicate is off-topic as per the FAQ. Try http://webapps.stackexchange.com

Comment: @wonea The link to the duplicate question isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

You might try a portable app that doesn't need to be installed, can be run directly off a usb drive, and leaves no registry entries or anything on the host computer, like [blender](http://portableapps.com/apps/graphics_pictures/blender_portable).

Comment: I can't execute exe files. :/ it's really backwards, my school (I'm the asker, just I didn't login as I asked that question at school, and I don't trust it with my Google Account)

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to model? http://floorplanner.com/ supports 3D flash-based models. It is for floor plans of houses, but you can build whatever you want in 3D using the basic tools they provide.